# Convert templates in drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Problem:
I'm Developing a website in Drupal 7. I want to use a template like "https://pixelgrade.com/demos/themes/" . I purchased it but there is no any tutorial or helping material to convert that type templates in Drupal theme.

Question:
**My question is Drupal 7 supported templates or not? How can i convert this template into Drupal 7 theme?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Pixelgrade themes are created for WordPress. WordPress and Drupal 7 are two different CMS and there is no way to use a WordPress template in Drupal simply because they are different software.

You will need to install WordPress in order to use the Listable theme, or buy a Drupal 7 template, sorry.